# NHibernate QueryOver over many tables

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

There is an entity **Effort** that has a property **List** and a property **AdType**
We have several **adTypes** enum objects and **specialLists** enum objects to select **`IList<Effort>`**

I do it in this way:

```
    return NHibernateSession.QueryOver<Effort>()
        .JoinQueryOver(effort => effort.AdType)
                .WhereRestrictionOn(adType => adType.Id)
                .IsIn(adTypes.Select(adt => (long)adt).ToList())
            .Clone()
            .JoinQueryOver(effort => effort.List)
                .WhereRestrictionOn(list => list.Id)
                .IsIn(specialLists.Select(sl => (long)sl).ToList())
            .List<Effort>();
```

as u can see I use a strange Clone() method that doesn't have any description. It works great.

In what way do you use QueryOver for such queries?

Comment: I am curious here, what happens if you omit the clone, also what SQL is fired of to the database?

Comment: Without Clone() it will not try do the following Join to Effort. It will try to do it to AdType. So there will not be  .JoinQueryOver(effort => effort.List) it will be .JoinQueryOver(adType => adType.....)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.JoinQueryOver(effort => effort.AdType)` will return a QueryOver with a subtype, here `AdType` `IQueryOver<Effort, Adtype>` instead of the original `IQueryOver<Effort, Effort>`. The first generic argument is the *queryType* and the second the type on which the methods are operating on. If you clone in between the whole query is copyied and returned as the basequery `IQueryOver<Effort, Effort>`.

To prevent the QueryOver to switch to the subtype there is JoinAlias which creates an alias instead of descending.

```
AdType adAlias = null;
ListType listAlias = null;

return NHibernateSession.QueryOver<Effort>()
    .JoinAlias(effort => effort.AdType, () => adAlias)
    .JoinAlias(effort => effort.List, () => listAlias)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => adAlias.Id).IsIn(adTypes.Cast<long>().ToList())
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => listAlias.Id).IsIn(specialLists.Cast<long>().ToList())
    .List<Effort>();
```

not that if you only Restrict on the Id of adtype and listtype then

```
return NHibernateSession.QueryOver<Effort>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(effort => effort.Adtype.Id).IsIn(adTypes.Cast<long>().ToList())
    .WhereRestrictionOn(effort => effort.List.Id).IsIn(specialLists.Cast<long>().ToList())
    .List<Effort>();
```